# Critical values of trace statistic of Johansen cointegration test for arbitrary number of I(1) variables

Tags: time-series, cointegration

I am trying to find the critical values of the trace statistic Johansen cointegration test for a large number of I(1) variables. However, I cannot find these values tabulated anywhere beyond n = 12 cointegration vectors. Is there any way to compute these values by simulation for n>12 (n ~ 50)? I am using the Python statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.coint_johansen package.

Thank you

Comment: Since this is primarily a statistical question, consider moving it to Cross Validated Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: Thank you Richard, I will answer it here since I found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the paper STATISTICAL ANALYSIS OF COINTEGRATION VECTORS (Johansen, 1987), I derived the following solution which gives a good approximation of the critical values:

Let $c(f) = f \rightarrow 0.85 - 0.58/f$ where $f$ is the number of degrees of freedom of your system. Then a good approximation of the trace statistic distribution is $c(2k^2) \chi^2(2k^2)$ where $k$ is the number of cointegrating vectors considered.

A Python script to compute the critical values:

```python
from scipy.stats import chi2
def c(ddf):
    return 0.85-0.58/ddf
def critical_value(q, ddf):
    return(c(ddf)*chi2.ppf(q = q, df = ddf))
```

Testing for $q = 0.9$ and for $k$ ranging from 1 to 10, I obtain:

```python
(k, critical value for f = 2*k**2)
(1, 2.579),
(2, 10.389),
(3, 21.254),
(4, 35.425),
(5, 52.959),
(6, 73.875),
(7, 98.18),
(8, 125.878),
(9, 156.972),
(10, 191.462)
```

We can see that these values are close to the ones reported by Johansen in his paper and the ones used in `statsmodels.tsa.coint_tables`.
For those interested in reading the paper, the relevant results are in page 9 and 22 (theorem 3 and 4).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sounds good. Did you have to read the whole paper, o was some section of it particularly relevant, and if so, which?

Comment: Thank you for correcting the formating! The relevant results are in page 9 and 22 (theorem 3 and 4). I read the first 11 pages which give quite a good understanding but skipped the proofs after page 12.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps you could include this by editing your answer, as not everyone reads comments.

Comment: I just did thank you for your comments Richard!

Comment: Thank you so much!